# Twilio cannot send SMS from Ionic ngcordova

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, sms, twilio, ngcordova

I want to send SMS from an Ionic framework hybrid application. Can anyone tell me how to do this? Please suggest me some reference link or code sample.

Comment: "Please suggest me some reference link or code sample." Stack Overflow isn't meant to suggest offsite resources. Please see #4 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tried Ionic myself for building hybrid apps, but I suspect it should work as you like given [examples from the community](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/twilio-ionic-framework-and-node-js-a-message-call-app/).

This utilizes the Node helper library https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node.